# What is the difference between $p(x, y\mid z)$ and $p(y\mid z,x)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

As title, what is the difference between $p(x,y\mid z)$ and $p(y\mid z,x)$, or they are the same? And more, is $p(x,y\mid z) p(z) = p(x,y,z)$ or $p(x,y\mid z) p(x,z) = p(x,y,z)$ ? Or should be $p(y\mid z,x)p(z,x) = p(x,y,z)$ ? Thanks for your answering.

Li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are most definitely not the same thing. The notation $p(x|y)$ is read as "what is the probability of $x$ happening conditioned on $y$ having had happened?" So it is inherently clear that $p(x,y|z) \neq p(x|y,z)$. Read it out loud to yourself to see this is the case. Joint probability distributions are - in this sense - very nonassociative.

Comment: Thanks WIlliams. P(x, y|z) means x and y happened on z happened OR x happened and y happened on z happened? Alternative speaking, is P((x,y)|z) or P(x,(y|z))?

Comment: It is the first of the two you wrote down. It's the probability of $x$ and $y$ happening given that $z$ happened.

Comment: Then how can I express x happened and y happened on z happened? By P(x; y|z) ?

Comment: Yes I think that is the standard notation.

Comment: Thank you very much, Williams. That's where I confused. :)

Comment: Shouldn't the word here be associative rather than commutative?

Comment: @Peter Yeah you're right. My mistake.